# django rest framework - request context key error

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework

I have two models (Like and News). I am using django-rest-framework to make a web api out of it.

```
class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

class News(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    ...
    likes = GenericRelation(Like)
```

A *Like object* has its own user field to store who liked the News object. Now to check if a specific user exists in any of the likes of a News object, I am getting request.user from a SerializerMethodField.

```
class NewsSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()
    likes_count = serializers.IntegerField(source='likes.count', read_only=True)
    user_in_likes = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = News
        fields = ('user', 'title', 'body', 'article_image', 'pub_date', 'likes_count', 'user_in_likes')

    def get_user_in_likes(self, obj):
        user = self.context['request'].user
        what = obj.likes.filter(user=user).exists()
        return what
```

When I go the /news/ url, I get the json objects including the `user_in_likes` to true/false for each news object.

However, I have another serialzer for different model which imports `NewsSerializer class` and other similar serializers:

```
class ActivityObjectRelatedField(serializers.RelatedField):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, User):
            serializer = UserSerializer(value)
        elif isinstance(value, Job):
            serializer = JobSerializer(value)
        elif isinstance(value, News):
            serializer = NewsSerializer(value)
        elif isinstance(value, Tender):
            serializer = TenderSerializer(value)
        else:
            raise Exception('Unexpected type of tagged object')
        return serializer.data    

class ActivitySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    actor = ActivityObjectRelatedField(read_only=True)
    target = ActivityObjectRelatedField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Activity
        fields = ('url', 'actor', 'verb', 'target', 'pub_date')
```

Now if I visit `/activities/`, to get the activities objects I am getting an error:

> KeyError at /activities/
>
> 'request'

And it points to the line of SerializerMethod of NewsSerialize class where `self.context['request'].user` is used.

> Exception Location:    /vagrant/myproject/news/serializers.py in get_user_in_likes, line 25

Again if I visit `/news/` url, everything is fine and I get news objects. What am I missing here? Why is `request` not being recognized in the `ActivitiesSerializer class`? Please help me solve this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are getting this error because **you are not passing `request` in the context when instantiating the `NewsSerializer` class or other similar serializers** in the `to_representation()` method.

You are manually instantiating the particular serializer class in `to_representation()` method. So, after instantiation, that particular serializer does not have access to `ActivitySerializer`'s `context` thereby leading to the error.

You can **[pass](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context) the `ActivitySerializer`'s `context` during instantiation** of the relevant serializer in the `to_representation()` method.

```
class ActivityObjectRelatedField(serializers.RelatedField):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, User):
            serializer = UserSerializer(value, context=self.context) # pass context
        elif isinstance(value, Job):
            serializer = JobSerializer(value, context=self.context) # pass context
        elif isinstance(value, News):
            serializer = NewsSerializer(value, context=self.context) # pass context
        elif isinstance(value, Tender):
            serializer = TenderSerializer(value, context=self.context) # pass context
        else:
            raise Exception('Unexpected type of tagged object')
        return serializer.data
```

Comment: So much helpful

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you don't populate the `context` dictionary of `NewsSerializer` with your request in the `/activities/` view.

You probably use a class based view provided by Django REST Framework which populates this dictionary for you (see the [`get_serializer_context()` method](http://www.cdrf.co/3.3/rest_framework.generics/ListAPIView.html#get_serializer_context)) and passes it to the `Serializer` instance. That's why it's automatically available to your serializer in your `/news/` view.

In your `/activities/` view, though, the context is passed to `ActivitySerializer` and isn't (automatically) propagated further from there. That's why there's no `request` key in your context dictionary of `NewsSerializer`. You would need to pass your request object to the `NewsSerializer` instance. To pass extra context to a Serializer you can add a `context` parameter containing a dictionary when instantiating (see the [DRF documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context)).